# awk add previously initiated variable bash

Tags: bash, variables, printing, awk

I've got a problem with adding variables to AWK.

I've got a file with the following input:

```
MainComputer>
Device ID: name1
Interface: 1
random text...
Device ID: name2
Interface: 2
random text....
Device ID: name3
Interface: 3
random text....
```

Now I want to print all the variables: What I already have:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(head -n 1 file)
var=$(echo $line | cut -d ">" -f1)
var2=$(awk '/Interface/  {print $2}' file)  
awk -v var3="$var" '/Device/ {print var3, "->", $2, "[Label: "$var2"]}' file
```

But the $var2 doesn't show an output, and if I put: var2 it gives an error.

Output I want:

```
MainComputer -> name1 [Label: 1]
MainComputer -> name2 [Label: 2]
MainComputer -> name3 [Label: 3]
```

And so on for the other 40 inputs....

But it only gives MainComputer -> name1 and an error on the interface label...

So I'm seeking a method for printing more than 1 var that I already initialized.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is the output you're looking for? Could you edit your question to show us?

Comment: Obviously, why have you assigned `-v var3="$var"` properly but then tried to use `$var2` inside. Shell variable do not expand in single quotes, your entire awk command is in single quotes.

Comment: Is it just that one line you want? Do you not want to show anything for `name2` and `name3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're attempting to do correctly, this could be better achieved in pure awk:

```
awk -F ': *' 'NR == 1 { sub(/>.*/, ""); name = $0; next } $1 == "Device ID" { dev = $2 } $1 == "Interface" { print name " -> " dev " [Label: " $2 "]" }' file
```

`-F ': *'` sets the field separator to the regex `: *` (matching a colon followed by an arbitrary number of spaces). The code works as follows:

```
NR == 1 {           # in the first line:
  sub(/>.*/, "")    # remove > and everything after it
  name = $0         # remember as machine name
  next              # do nothing else
}
$1 == "Device ID" { # after that: In device lines
  dev = $2          # remember device name
}
                    # In interface lines: print remembered info
$1 == "Interface" {
  print name " -> " dev " [Label: " $2 "]"
}
```

This will show all lines in the file formatted the way you show in the question. If you want to filter for a particular line, this could be amended as follows:

```
awk -v filter="name2" -F ': *' 'NR == 1 { sub(/>.*/, ""); name = $0; next } $1 == "Device ID" { dev = $2 } $1 == "Interface" && dev == filter { print name " -> " dev " [Label: " $2 "]" }' file
```

That is, make a variable `filter` known to awk with `-v filter=value`, and amend the code

```
NR == 1 {
  sub(/>.*/, "")
  name = $0
  next
}
$1 == "Device ID" {
  dev = $2     
}
$1 == "Interface" && dev == filter {         # <-- here
  print name " -> " dev " [Label: " $2 "]"
}
```